How can I alter my cron job so that unwanted space is not introduced?
I am running a cron job with the following syntax:
{ crontab -l -u root 2>/dev/null; echo "10 2 * * * python3 main.py /data/log/access.log-\$(date -d \"yesterday\" \"+%Y%m%d\") /data/log/status.json > /dev/null 2>&1"; } \

This is my syntax when I am deploying. However when I see it within the container there is an Unwanted space introduced at the start of "yesterday" command. I want to pass the argument as yesterdays access log so I am adding that postfix.
Initially when I wrote this , it was on the base image Alpine but due to other technical reasons we migrated it to Debian base image. Now the cron job is failing as the program is not getting second argument. This is my cron job log.
CRON[1495]: (root) CMD (python3 /main.py /data/log/access.log-$(date -d yesterday + )

What can be done? I want to refrain myself from adding an additional shell script for running this code.

You need to escape % in crontab entries.

You can simplify this by using single quotes around the echo argument. Then you don't need to escape double quotes and dollar signs.
